# Difference between UIStackView and Auto Layout Anchor

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uistackview

I'm newly learning about `UIStackView` and trying to grasp the difference between applying the Auto Layout individually to each UI element yourself vs. using the stack view.

Let's say you have 5 `UILabels` and you want to space them out equally. I can either use something like Auto Layout Anchors:

```swift
var previous: UILabel?

for label in [label1, label2, label3, label4, label5] {
    label.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 88).isActive = true
    
    if let previous = previous {
        label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: previous.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    } else {
        label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    }
    
    previous = label
}
```

or the Visual Format Language:

```swift
let viewsDictionary = ["label1": label1, "label2": label2, "label3": label3, "label4": label4, "label5": label5]
view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[label1(labelHeight@999)]-[label2(label1)]-[label3(label1)]-[label4(label1)]-[label5(label1)]-(>=10)-|", options:[], metrics: metrics, views: viewsDictionary))
```

or use stack view and set the distribution setting at `equalSpacing` along the main axis.

These are rough examples, but am I correct in understanding that you can pretty much do everything that stack view does with either Auto Layout Anchors or with Visual Format Language, but stack view makes it easier?

Or are there exclusive benefits of using the stack view that can't be done with Auto Layout Anchors or Visual Format Language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Format Language has a ***lot*** of limitations. My impression (could be wrong) is that Apple is not even developing it anymore - it's just there for backward compatibility.

For your *simple* layout example, you're right. You can do the same thing with your loop as you can do with a stack view.

However... suppose you want those 5 labels to be centered vertically on the screen? Or inside another view? If they're in a stack view, you simple constrain the position of the stack view.

Or, suppose at runtime you want to add more labels (or other views), or insert `label-2A` between `label2` and `label3`? With your looped constraints, you have a problem. With a stack view, `stack.insertArrangedSubview(label2A, at: 2)` (indexes are zero-based) and you're done.

Stack views also have many other arrangement features that make life very simple when designing complex UIs.

Take a search for `UIStackView` for some examples - or even just browse some posts here tagged with `uistackview`... I think you'll very quickly see the advantages.

Answer (score 1):

The use of these two elements is optional. StackView makes it easier to implement items that change (add / remove). As you wrote, StackView is a simplification. With Constraints you can get the same effect as in StackView but you will have to get a little tired.

Answer (score 1):

As all UI controls `UIStackView` has its own purpose and use cases and probably you **can** implement everything it does, but you'll waste a lot of time :).
E.g. `UIStackView` has 5 distribution variants, vertical & horizontal, can be used with all the auto-layout features to support various screen sizes etc..

Also, most likely it is way better tested than a custom code you'd write.
The less lines of code you have to write, the better :)